# Is possible with CSS or with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css

I need your help with a small question.
I will wish that when I hover over a #div element, another element changes to CSS. Is it possible ?

I give you an example below

```css
li.menu-sub-item {
  display: none;
}

/* Here I don't know how do this but */

/* When I hover on .menu-item */
li.menu-item:hover {
/* .menu-sub-item will be display */
  li.menu-sub-item {
  display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="menu-main-menu">
  <li class="menu-item">
    <a href="https://www.test.com">Home</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li class="menu-sub-item"></li>
      <a href="https://www.test.com">Profil</a>
    </ul>
  </li>
</div>
```

Thx in advance !

Comment: Do you mean `li.menu-item:hover li.menu-sub-item` ??

Comment: Your markup is invalid. List items must be children of a list element.

Comment: "another element changes to CSS" - what does that mean?

Comment: I just don't know how to say that : when `li.menu-item:hover` display `li.menu-sub-item`

Comment: @Rismo look at the first comment from Suraj Rao. That's how you do it.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Answer (score 1):

You can use `+` or `~` CSS selector with a tag and then join `ul.sub-menu` with it.

so it can be write like this `li.menu-item a:hover+ul.sub-menu`

You can read more about CSS selectors here https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

```css
/* Hide submenu by default */

ul.sub-menu {
  display: none;
}


/* Show menu when prev relative a hovers */

li.menu-item a:hover+ul.sub-menu {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu-main-menu">
  <li class="menu-item">
    <a href="https://www.test.com">Home</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li class="menu-sub-item">
        <a href="https://www.test.com">Profil</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</div>
```

Comment: What is "this"? Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: @VijayHardaha your `HTML` code is wrong even though browsers can still understand it. Those `</ul>...</li>` closing tags are misplaced.

Comment: @VijayHardaha add the selector information to the answer, not a comment. It's better to put **all** of the information in the answer itself.

Comment: Maybe that's it

Comment: Updated the answer. added basic explanation and ref. link to learn CSS selectors also fixed the HTML closing tag issue noticed by @ths

Comment: @VijayHardaha thank you for considering what i've pointed and making the required changes.